# Kodak ESP 5250 Not Finding Router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, printer

I have a Kodak ESP 5250 and a TP-LINK AC750 Dual Band Router. I have struggled for some time to get my WiFi set up and have resorted to linking my printer up via USB to my desktop - not an ideal situation as my desktop is rarely used beyond printing.

The printer is located in the same room as my router and it can pick up other routers in my apartment building. Just not mine. I have checked to ensure my SSID is broadcasting. Along with searching for the router, I have tried WPS Push and manually typing in the SSID and Network Key. No joy with either.

I also found instructions online that said that if all else fails, connect via IP. On that score, it hasn't worked but this could be operator error rather than technological.

I've just started a new college class so getting this resolved would make life so much easier so any recommendations / instructions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get my printer set up.

I don't know exactly what did it in the end because I tried fiddling around with various settings on my router. Eventually, the SSID started to display on my printer after I disabled WPS on my router and then enabled it again.

I'm not about to start playing with it again to work out why it came to life. This has been a pain in my rear for ages. So I'm just going to consider myself lucky.

Comment: I was actually about to recommend this, since the printer states that it _Requires_ WPS.  Glad to hear you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

Your printer only supports IEEE 802.11b/g WiFi protocols. Your router, on the other hand, supports ac and n as well as b/g. Its setup will have several possible settings, probably including "802.11ac only" or "802.11n/ac". Make sure the setting you choose includes 802.11b/g.

To set it, log into the router as admin, click the Advanced tab and check the WiFi settings.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I've logged into the router as admin and the only b/g option is on the 2.4GHz band. So, I turned off the 5GHz band so I could set up my printer. Unfortunately, still no joy. Neither the SSID appears on my printer and the WPS Push does nothing.

Comment: Can you post an image of the setup page for the router?